# What can cause IISExpress private bytes to keep increasing without any significant change in managed heap?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, out-of-memory, glimpse

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that uses Windsor for injecting repositories and NHibernate sessions. Today, for the first time, I hit an `OutOfMemoryException`. At first I thought it might be because I wasn't releasing any of the `Transient` objects that Windsor was creating. As a quick experiment, I turned all of those into `PerWebRequest` lifestyle, but it doesn't seem to have affected the memory usage pattern in a big way -- it still keeps going up.

- I'm not doing any caching
- I'm not using any unmanaged resources
- I *am* doing JSON serialization of several anonymous objects
- The action that I'm using for stress testing just returns a tiny JSON object (32 bytes), so no large objects are involved anywhere

What could cause IISExpress private bytes to keep going up when my managed heap size is stable (verified with Perfmon)?

What would be the right tool to debug this? I'm assuming CLR profilers may not be helpful because Perfmon doesn't show any leak in the managed heap.

Comment: I've just verified with SOS that the GC heap is, indeed, just around 32MB or so. Yet, w3wp.exe is using up 713MB and still climbing. Any ideas?

Comment: so the problem is with non-managed memory?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Yes, oddly enough it looks like it's being caused by Glimpse. I don't have an explanation for it yet, but turning it off seems to have fixed the leak.

Comment: @Ragesh - We'd love to work with you to figure out why Glimpse is causing this issue for you. If you wouldn't mind, email me. My address is my StackOverflow username AT gmail.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Memory usage seems to be stable after I disabled [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/).

I don't know what it could possibly be doing to leak unmanaged memory, but just setting `on="false"` in the Glimpse configuration section in web.config instantly makes the memory usage stable.

Comment: I can confirm I've had the same memory-leak issues with Glimpse as well in production.

Comment: Did you mean enabled="false" ?

Comment: @NelsonReis No, I meant `on="false"`. This may have changed in a more recent build of Glimpse. The version I was using then worked with "on" instead of "enabled".

Comment: The version I have is the 0.87 and the property is "enabled", but I got the idea and it helped me find this issue that was bringing my server down. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect I had the same problem on my production server. I had a time out exception and I could see `Glimpse` mentioned in the stack trace